# Does level of pollution determine if a rainbow will be formed?

Tags: reflection, refraction, atmospheric-science, weather

Today I saw a rainbow after almost a decade. I live in Noida (a city) in India. Most people I know believe that: **we don't see rainbows nowadays because of pollution** and now after nearly 3 months since the COVID lock-down, the pollution must have come down and the rainbow was visible. Is this belief true?

You can see news(pictures) about the rainbow [here](https://inshorts.com/m/en/amp_news/double-rainbow-spotted-in-delhincr-parts-of-haryana-after-rainfall-pics-surface-1590932520797)

According to this site https://aqicn.org/map/delhi/ PM2.5 in Delhi(very close to Noida) today is $74$ and last year in 2019 on this day was $151$.

how does pollution impact rainbows?

here is an analysis related to this question published in 1999: [Scientific Attitude on Understanding Disappearance of Rainbow](http://weather.ou.edu/~spark/AMON/v3_n2/Editorials/rainbow.html). thanks to user [Keith McClary](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/6535/keith-mcclary) for finding this.

Comment: *now after nearly 3 months since the COVID lock-down, the pollution must have come down and the rainbow was visible* This is very poor logic.  Just because *one* event happens after *one* event in a loosely related time frame, that does *not* make them cause and effect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more suitable for [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @StephenG the logic is we could see rainbows frequently until ~10 years ago but not since then, and today I saw one so what has changed during lock-down? Air-pollution. There are other similar claims [https://www.cnbc.com/2020/04/23/coronavirus-photos-show-effect-of-air-pollution-drops-from-global-lockdown.html]

Comment: @StephenG I asked the question on Earth Science SE as well now. Should I delete it from here?

Comment: Climate change and urban growth could all affect local weather patterns, as well as sunspot activity cycles and a hundred other factors (assuming this claim is correct - I'd kind of like to see it questioned on [skeptics.se]).  As for deletion, I've no firm opinion on that (and keep in mind I'm just an ordinary member, not a moderator).

Comment: I think the biggest problem to see rainbows in urban areas is to have a view of the horizon unobstructed by some wall or tall building, or just not being indoors most of the time. In some places you're only able to see the sky if you look up. If were not for the pandemic, where you would be the time you saw the rainbow? At work in some office? Could you still see it?